# The action 'create' could not be found for UserVacationDaysController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've seen this question asked everywhere, but it never solves my problem. Heres my controller:

```
class UserVacationDaysController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @user_vacation_days = UserVacationDay.new 
  end

  def create 

    @user_vacation_days = UserVacationDay.create(params[:user_vacation_day]) 
    @user_vacation_days.user = current_user 

    # @user_vacation_days.calculate_work_days
    # (another param that holds date range will get passed in)
    # puts @user_vacation_days.errors.inspect


    if @user_vacation_days.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = "Request Sent"
        redirect_to dashboard_index_path

        request_vacation_days # method from model. model method calls method in employee_mailer 

    else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong, please try again"
        render :new

    end

  end

end
```

And here is my view (form).

```
<h2>Request Days Off</h2>

<%= form_for :user_vacation_days, :url => user_vacation_days_path do |f| %> 

  <div><%= f.label "How much time off would you like to take?" %>
  <%= f.number_field :number_of_days %></div>  

  <div><%= f.label "Argue your case, slave" %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %></div>  

  <div><%= f.submit "Request Time Off" %></div>

<% end %>
```

The routes for my 2 controller methods are

```
      user_vacation_days POST   /user_vacation_days(.:format)     user_vacation_days#create
   new_user_vacation_day GET    /user_vacation_days/new(.:format) user_vacation_days#new
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I've looked all over the place, and I can't find anything. I can't think of any reason why the controller method wouldn't be found. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add `:method => 'POST'` to your form_for and see if that clears it up?

Comment: Weird.. Did you try to restart your rails server?

Comment: I restarted the rails server and it worked. Thanks Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<%= form_for :user_vacation_days, :url => user_vacation_days_path do |f| %>` what happens if you use `<%= form_for @user_vacation_days, :url => user_vacation_days_path do |f| %>`

Also, does a `User` have_many `VacationDay`? You might want to change to resourceful routes, and have vacation days nested.

```
config/routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :user_vacation_days
end

in your new action under UserVacationDaysContoller #may want to rename this to just VacationDays since the nesting implies

def new
  @user = current_user
  @user_vacation_days = @user.vacation_days.build
end
```

Comment: A user does have_many :vacation_days. I'll look into nesting the resources. that seems like a good idea